# How do I call onNext immediately after map returns an object?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have this code where an observable takes the contactUri, and returns the cursor. I use rxjava for this purpose because I want this to be done on the UI thread. Anyways, my question is, after the map returns the cursor, I want to do something with the cursor, how do I call onNext so I can perform further operations with the cursor?

```
            io.reactivex.Observable.just(contactUri)
                    .map(new Function<Uri, Cursor>() {
                        @Override
                        public Cursor apply(Uri uri) throws Exception {
                            return getActivity().getContentResolver()
                                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Cursor>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Cursor cursor) {
                                //do something
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: edited the code in.

Comment: You should read about how RxJava works. Observable.just create eagerly an Observable which will pass  contactUri down the pipeline. After just, map will be called and transforms the value. If you subscribe to the created Observable with subscribe you will be called, when the value has been processed. In the onNext you describe what you want to do, when the value has been passed down to the subscriber.

Comment: Do that something with it before you return it from the map().